# Retrieving raster layer names from a raster stack R

Tags: raster, r, layers

I have a raster stack with many layers and I want to compare the layers that contain the maximum value using cell by cell comparison and finally retrieve the layer names from the raster stack on each cell that contain the max value. Here are sample names of the layers in the stack.

[1] "rf_0.0.0"   "rf_0.0.30"  "rf_0.0.60"  "rf_0.30.0"  "rf_0.30.30"
[6] "rf_0.30.60" "rf_0.60.0"  "rf_0.60.30" "rf_0.60.60"

any support please?

---

But what I need is to get the layer name (i.e. "rf_0.30.0") and store it on some variable for all of the raster.

Comment: Do you want to do it iteratively over all the posible cells or you want something like a function that returns the name of the layer when you input the location of the cell ?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is `which.max` from the `raster` package in R. The documentation is here: https://rdrr.io/cran/raster/man/which.minmax.html. The function `which.max` will return the a raster layer from your stack that has the greatest value for each pixel. For example, if for a given cell your "rf_0.30.0" layer has the greatest value of all the layers in your raster stack, that cell value will be 4 in your output raster. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks @Zackary Werner.

Comment: No problem. Please mark as answered if it worked for you! @Amsalu

Comment: @@Zackary Werner, it is a greate hint but what I need is to get the layer name (i.e. "rf_0.30.0") and store it on some variable for all of the raster.

Comment: @Amsalu got it. You may need to do something like this: ```rat <- levels(r)[[1]]
rat$landcover <- c("Pine", "Oak", "Meadow")
rat$code <- c(12,25,30)
levels(r) <- rat
r```. See more here: https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/raster/html/factor.html

Answer (score 0):

To get the name of the raster stack with the highest value for a cell you can do this:

```
Rstack <- readRDS('vsi.rds')

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# SINGLE CELL CALCULATION
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Cell selection (by row, col)
row <- 2000
col <- 5000

# Get the max layer value for a defined cell...
cellnumber <- cellFromRowCol(Rstack, row, col)
cellvalues <- Rstack[cellnumber]
maxindex <- which.max(cellvalues)

# Store name
maxname <- names(Rstack)[[maxindex]]
maxname
```

Depending on your goal you can make a function where your input is the row/col of the cell or the cell number (see cellnumber object in code) of interest. In case you want to create an object with the names of each cell by cell comparison you can adapt the previous code. Something like this:

```
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# ALL CELLS CALCULATION
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
maxnames <- list()
for(i in 1:cellnumber(Rstack)){
        # Get the max layer value for a defined cell...
        cellvalues <- Rstack[i]
        maxindex <- which.max(cellvalues)

        # Store name
        maxnames[[i]] <- ifelse(length(maxindex)==0, NA, names(Rstack)[[maxindex]])
}
```

I hope this helps.